# central didDiscoverPeripheral: method not invoking

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

My code:`centralManagerDidUpdateState`

```
NSDictionary *opts=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO],CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey, nil];
[mgr scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:opts];
```

Then central didDiscoverPeripheral: method not invoking

```
 [self.peripherals addObject:peripheral];
```

Comment: Could you show more? In what case you start eh scan? Is `mrg` nil? What kind of device are you trying to find?

Comment: how to check mgr is nil?I m trying on Bluetooth low energy device ,peripherals is NSMutable array to show list of peripherals in tableview,but didDiscoverPeripheral: method not calling.

Comment: Let's start again: With LightBlue app, do you find your device?

Comment: Please show the full method for `centralManagerDidUpdateState`

Comment: its shows log msg in this caseCBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn but NSDictionary *opts=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO],CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey, nil]; opts shows 1key/pair value not getting into didDiscoverPeripheral: